# How to make a macro which gives back a string into the source code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macros

Example: I want to do this:

```
METHODNAME(5) {
    // do something 
}
```

which results in:

```
- (void)animationStep5 {
    // do something 
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Basically, what I need is a way to generate a real source code string before the program is compiled, so the compiler does see `- (void)animationStep5`...

Or maybe there's something different than a macro, which can help here to auto-generate method names (not at run-time)?

Comment: Why?  This seems like a gross abuse of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the concatenation operator

`#define METHODNAME(i) -(void)animationStep##i`

you can call it like

`METHODNAME(5){}`

This expands to 
`-(void)animationStep5{}`

Answer (score 2):

As was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896446/can-a-macro-also-generate-a-method-name/2896455#2896455), the objective-C preprocessor is very close to the C one.

You should have a look at the examples posted there, and have a look at [C proprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). You will simply have to use the `##` syntax of the preprocessor, to concatenate the method name, and the number you want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the objective-c preprocessor behaves the same as the standard C one, you can use something like:

```
#define PASTE(a, b) a##b
#define METHODNAME(n) PASTE(animationStep,n)
```

to join the required bits together. This means that

```
METHODNAME(5)
```

gets translated to

```
animationStep5
```

(you may need to add the "void" from your question to the macro definitino depending on exactly what it is you need to do).